# How do I stop byobu from launching at login?

Tags: ubuntu, byobu

I would like to turn off byobu from launching by default on my Ubuntu computer, how can I do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can permanently disable byobu on login by executing the following command:

```
byobu-disable
```

You can also turn it off on the fly and get to a bare metal login by skipping it entirely before you ssh in:

```
ssh -t yourhost.com bash
```

or

```
LC_BYOBU=0 ssh yourhost.com
```

And you can globally set this in your environment, affecting all of your outgoing SSH session by adding this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export LC_BYOBU=0
```

Note that you could also `export LC_BYOBU=1` to globaly *enable* byobu at login for all of your outgoing ssh connections.